# Как получить ID в боте телеграм, в личное сообщение бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
bot.send_message(5517014795, f"Сумма Обмена: {course}\n\n"                                   f"Сумма к Получению: {float('{0:.8f}'.format(course / (price['bitcoin']['rub'] * 1.03)))} BTC\n\n"
                                     f"На кошелёк: {wallet['proverka']}\n\n"
                                     f"Время Заявки: {datetime.datetime.now()}\n\n"
                                     f"От Пользователя:")
```

Нужно чтобы в пункте от пользователя отображался его id

Comment: Лучше приводите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]), чтобы не гадать что у вас в коде :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
f"От Пользователя: {message.from_user.id}"
```

Объект `message` у вас должен передаваться как параметр функции-обработчика

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ДаниилКиселев, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ДаниилКиселев, если мой ответ помог, то проголосуйте (стрелка вверх) и отметьте его как принятым (галочка внизу)